# Naming for static final fields of java.io.File are not standard

Tags: java, oracle, static, naming-conventions, sun

I'm preparing to SCJP and have observed interesting thing.

Sun naming conventions are not followed for constants:

```
File.separatorChar
File.separator
File.pathSeparatorChar
File.pathSeparator
```

How it can be explained?

Perhaps, some historical issue or just typo?

Comment: Hm, interesting! I assume historical issue and later backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

None of those are constants, technically (see the definition of a [constant expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313)). A constant's value is known at compile time. I believe that the uppercase-with-underscores naming convention only applies to actual constants and not just any `static final` field. As to why they aren't constants, they are of course file system dependent and have to be looked up for the current file system at runtime.

(It is, though, very common in Java code to use the same naming convention for all `static final` fields regardless of whether they're technically constants or not.)

Comment: A big clue that they aren't constants would be the lack of the `final` keyword for them in the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: This is indeed the reason. Compile-time constants can be in-lined. These values, of course, cannot, because they depend on the runtime environment.

Comment: yes,looks like you are correct. Actually,here is official constants list:http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html and there are some non-standard naming constants there,e.g. in swing lib

Comment: @R. Bemrose: They are actually `static final`, though... it looks like not even constants have `final` in Javadoc. Hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: Oh, hmm, you're right.  I was under the impression that they were marked `final`  in the JavaDoc.  Whoops.